# How to add/substract with c_double_Array?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using `ctypes` to interface with a DLL written in C and I created an array with this:

```
foo = (c_double * 1000)()
bar = (c_double * 1000)()
```

I can get all the values with `foo[:]` and the type is:

```
type(foo)
c_double_array_1000
```

However I cannot subtract foo with bar:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'c_double_Array_1000' and 'c_double_Array_1000'
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Arrays don't support subtraction.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can't subtract an array but you can subtract the values in an array.

Comment: I am trying to substract value-wise my array. Example: `[1,2,3] - [0,1,2]` = `[1,1,1]`.

Comment: you will probably have to use a loop to loop through the arrays and do the subtractions.

Comment: Isn't a better solution using `NumPy` or something like this?

Comment: Don't use ctypes for arithmetic! It's for interop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned [nowox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612235/nowox), one way to avoid the loop is to use `numpy`.

Try this:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
a = (ctypes.c_int * 10)(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
b = (ctypes.c_int * 10)(5,0,5,0,5,0,5,0,5,0)

x = np.array(a)
y = np.array(b)

x - y
```

will gives you:

```
array([ 4, -2,  2, -4,  0, -6, -2, -8, -4,  0])
```

However if you don't want to deal with modules as [NendoTaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4889443/nendotaka) does. You will need to use a loop and the [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) answer is the right one.

Comment: To avoid copying use `x = np.frombuffer(a); y = np.frombuffer(b)`. Then to go back to a ctypes array without copying you can use `result = type(a).from_buffer(x - y)`.

Comment: In case you're interested in details, Python's buffer protocol conveys the correct data type and size in the `np.frombuffer` call. The ctypes arrays, which actually own the memory, are referenced  as `x.base` and `y.base`, and `x.flags.owndata == False` because it doesn't own the data. For the ctypes `from_buffer` call, the `x - y` NumPy array, which owns the memory of the result array, is referenced in the `result._objects` dict. Also `result._b_needsfree_ == 0` because the ctypes object doesn't own the memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
foo = (ctypes.c_double * 3)(14, 22, 37)
bar = (ctypes.c_double * 3)(0, 1, 2)
diff = [foo[i]-bar[i] for i in range(len(foo))]
print diff
```

Comment: One would probably want `diff` to be the same array type instead of a list, e.g. `diff = type(foo)(*(f - b for f,b in zip(foo, bar)));` `print(*diff, sep=', ')`. (For Python 2 this requires `from __future__ import print_function` and for efficiency `from future_builtins import zip`.)